# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch NSClassFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It's been asked a dozen times but this error is a result of several different causes and I have no idea if my problem is relevant to any other causes.

I get these errors in console:

```
    2014-03-17 16:15:41.190 [31659:70b] setting to solo ambient
    2014-03-17 16:15:42.606 [31659:70b] backing dimensions: (640,960)
    2014-03-17 16:15:42.835 [31659:70b] no other audio playing
    2014-03-17 16:15:42.836 [31659:70b] no audio player..
    2014-03-17 16:15:42.854 [31659:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
    (lldb)
```

I get  Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 message in this code:

```
#import <SemiSecret/SemiSecret.h>

@implementation SemiSecretFont

- (NSString *) description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SemiSecretFont: name:%@, size:%.1f>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), size];
}

+ (SemiSecretFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)name
            size:(CGFloat) size;
{
  //dynamically search for a class with this name
  **Class klass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Font", name]); //error is on this line**
  //NSLog(@"looking for font: %@", name);
  //  NSLog(@"klass: %@", klass);
  SemiSecretFont * font = nil;
  if (klass)
   // font = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
    font = [[(SemiSecretFont *)[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
  return font;
}

- (id) fontWithSize:(CGFloat)s
{
  Class klass = [self class];
  SemiSecretFont * f = nil;
  //f = [[[klass alloc] initWithSize:s] autorelease];
f = [[(SemiSecretFont *)[klass alloc] initWithSize:size] autorelease];
  return f;
 }

 //this is not meant to be instantiated directly!
 - (id) initWithSize:(CGFloat)fontsize
 {
 if ((self = [super init])) {
size = fontsize;
font = nil;
   }
 return self;
    }
```

In AppDelegate, I have:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

   //in canabalt, we never want linear filtering (not even on ipad)
   [SemiSecretTexture setTextureFilteringMode:SSTextureFilteringNearest];

   [application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
       animated:NO];

   game = [[Canabalt alloc] init];

   //preload textures here, now that opengl stuff should be created
   preloadTextureAtlases();

   return YES;
      }

 - (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   [FlxG didEnterBackground];
 }

 - (void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   [FlxG willEnterForeground];
 }

 - (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   [FlxG willResignActive];
 }

 - (void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   [FlxG didBecomeActive];
 }

 - (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
 {
 }

 - (void) dealloc
 {
   [game release];
   [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

I am also trying to figure out how to make it so that audio player will be ignored.  I want the game to be played normally.

Comment: You didn't tell anything about how you are initializing the key window at your "game".

Comment: Apparently, as Adithya mentioned, I don't have rootViewController set.  Trying to figure out how to set it.  Any ideas?

Comment: first of all, you need to create a window. it can be done in different ways: programatically or automatically from the `.nib` or `storyboard` file set at `info.plist`. Check [Creating and Configuring a Window](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html) section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is fairly simple. 
In the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, the `rootViewController` property of the `window` is to be set; which does not seem to be happening in your code.
If you are doing it in storyboard / xib then you are not doing it right, as stated by the error `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

You can refer the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html) for more info on `window` and its `rootViewController`. To be precise, scroll down to the end of that page.

Comment: any idea how to set it?

Comment: @user3290191 Are you setting the window rootviewcontroller in xib or using a storyboard?

Comment: This is going to sound very dumb but how do I know if the game is using xib or storyboard?  The game is an open-sourced game made by somebody else and is outdated so I'm trying to fix it up.

Comment: I'm not sure about the game integration you are trying. I have updated my answer with the link to apple docs. Hope it helps.